# Android - Removing and adding views won't work after change of screen orientation?

Tags: android, screen-orientation, viewgroup

i have experienced some strange behavior of my dynamically added views after screen orientation change. I really would appreciate some help here...

I have a base layout for my activity, which is a LinearLayout that contains a ScrollView and a backButton.

```
<LinearLayout
  ...>
  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_containerForDynamicallyAddedLinearLayouts"
    ...>
  </ScrollView>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/backButton"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my Activity i am creating a lot of LinearLayouts dynamically, which are also containing some kind of navigation buttons to switch between the LinearLayouts. These LinearLayouts are stored in an ArrayList (panelViewList) and are added and removed from the ScrollView  at runtime (depending on which nav button was clicked). The backButton just removes all views from the ScrollView.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
  if (view.getId() == R.id.backButton) {
    scrollViewContainer.removeAllViews();
  } else {
    String target = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
    scrollViewContainer.removeAllViews();
    for (LinearLayout ll : panelViewList) {                           
      if (ll.getContentDescription().toString().equals(target)) {     
        xmlVerticalScrollView.addView(ll);                            
        break;                                                        
      }
  }
}
```

This works really fine without any problems UNTIL the screen orientation got changed. After screen orientation got changed, nothing will happen when you click on the nav buttons in the dynamically added LinearLayouts (no removing views, no adding target view). BUT clicking on the backButton still works fine (all views will be removed). Why?

Additionally info: I have debugger breakpoints set for the case of the back button being clicked and the (else)case of a nav button being clicked on:
After orientation change, when i click on a nav button in the dynamically created LinearLayout, the inspection of scrollViewContainer says that all children are null (this is wrong). But when i click on the backButton, scrollViewContainer has the correct children. This is very strange...

Answer (score 0):

Screen Rotation will redraw the entire screen in the new orientation, we can prevent it with overriding configuration changes.

add  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" under your screen declaration in Android Manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

And Override onConfigurationChanged(Configuration) in your activity like

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```